Algorithm to count k-edge even-regular subgraphs of a graph?
Given an undirected graph G which is not necessarily connected, I am looking for an algorithm (or formula) that counts the number of spanning subgraphs of G that is even-regular and contains exactly k edges.
The property that the subgraphs are spanning is not important --- the vertex sets of the subgraphs do not really matter to me. The subgraphs need not be connected, but they must be even-regular.
Ideally the algorithm should not be a brute-force enumeration and filtering over all subgraphs, as the time complexity of that is too high. Bonus if optimality can be shown or is known, but any algorithm that outperforms brute-force in complexity is hugely appreciated.
From the Wikipedia page on the cycle space of graphs, I understand there is a simple formula for the total number of such subgraphs, summed over all possible k. However, in my use-case, I need to resolve their counts for each k individually.
My own literature search has not turned up anything useful, but there is a possibility that I simply do not know the suitable keywords for this type of algorithms (if they exist), hence my asking to see if anyone is better-versed in this area.

Can you add your code, inputs and expected outputs?

"The property that the subgraphs are spanning is not important"  So why mention it?

Is this right: if G = K4 & k=2, then we'd want the 4 K3s, the 6 C4s for a total of 10.
